# Recover deleted resource group

Tags: azure

If one were to submit a support request to Microsoft would they be able to recover a deleted resource group in Azure? There were quit a few resources in this group.

Comment: Try it, I would say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to restore a deleted resource group.

You can submit a support request to Microsoft, but unfortunately they won't be able to help you.

Resource Group deletion is irreversible.